# Text-only taskbar icons

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

I installed a mac theme on my win7 and I have pinned icons on my taskbar:

[image]

I want to display a text only like this:

[image]

without icons like on Mac without using 3rd party programs.

What do I need to modify?

Answer (score 0):

The taskbar is more like the object doc on the bottom of the mac, not the menubar. In windows, the menu bar comes with the application.

Unfortunately what you want is not possible, because both Operating Systems are totally different from eachother.